# LINQ Select and Group By

Tags: c#, linq

Fairly new to LINQ and think what I'm trying to do should be easy.  I have a list of products (`ProductId`, `ProductDesc`) and I'm trying to pull a subset of that list and group it by `ProductId`.  From there, I'd like to bind that subset to a listView.  Here's the query I'm working on:

```
productCounts = (from record in wowReportData 
                 group record by record.ProductID 
                 into grouping
                 orderby grouping.Key
                 select new topProduct 
                 { 
                     ProductID = grouping.Key, 
                     Quantity = grouping.Count(),
                     Name = grouping.
                 }).ToList();
```

and here's the class I'm trying to populate:

```
public class topProduct
{
    public string ProductID { get; set; }
    public int Quantity { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public topProduct() { }

    public topProduct(string productId, string productDesc, int downloadCount)
    {
        this.ProductID = productId;
        this.Name = productDesc;
        this.Quantity = downloadCount;
    }
}
```

I had it working fine with just displaying the `productId` and the count but I need to add the description to the display as well.  I'm confused as to how to add the product description when I'm doing the grouping.

Comment: `grouping` is now a list of `wowReportData` grouped by `ProductID`. you could do `grouping.First().Name` if the name is a part of `wowReportData` but im not sure what you want to place in `Name`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I assume that there is only one name for each `ProductId` so you want to be grouping by 2 fields for that:

```
productCounts = (from record in wowReportData 
                 group record by new { record.ProductID, record.Name } into grouping
                 orderby grouping.Key.ProductID
                 select new topProduct 
                 { 
                     ProductID = grouping.Key.ProductID, 
                     Quantity = grouping.Count(),
                     Name = grouping.Key.Name
                 }).ToList();
```

If that is not the case then use `FirstOrDefault` and specify how to select it

---

Also, just a bit about C# - please look about naming conventions [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms229045(v=vs.110).aspx) and [here](http://www.dofactory.com/reference/csharp-coding-standards)

Comment: Spoke too soon, not getting design time errors but  productCounts isn't getting populated with anything.  Should I be casting this to a list of TopProduct objects?

Comment: @TrevorGoodchild - what do you mean not being populated. When you debug what do you see

Comment: sorry, got pulled into a fire drill.  The error is:{"At least one object must implement IComparable."}

Comment: @TrevorGoodchild - I did have a mistake at first OrderBy on the entire key object instead of just the id. Fixed it before. Is your version the one like above?

Comment: Yeah, that was it.  So what's the story on that?  Are we creating a new key out of productId and productDesc?  And thanks for the reference articles too, very helpful.

Answer (score 0):

```
productCounts = (from record in wowReportData 
                 group record by new { record.ProductID, record.Name } into grouping
                 orderby grouping.Key.ProductID
                 select new topProduct 
                 { 
                     ProductID = grouping.Key.ProductID, 
                     Quantity = grouping.Sum(t=>t.Quantity),
                     Name = grouping.Key.Name
                 }).ToList();
```

the aggregate sum should be Quantity calculated like this